# How to transfer data between AWS volumes?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, storage

I have two p2.xlarge instances (A and B), each with their own 75 GB EBS backed storage. I need to get all of the data from volume A onto volume B. My first thought was to start both instances and `scp` data from one to the other, however, this is not permitted  according to the following error message:

```
Error starting instances
You have requested more instances (2) than your current instance limit of 1 allows for the specified instance type. Please visit http://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/ec2-request to request an adjustment to this limit.
```

I have thought of a couple other options:

1. start a new instance of a different type and mount copies of volumes
   A and B to it. Then use `scp` to transfer the data (this seems
   awfully convoluted).
2. Make a copy of volume A and mount it on instance B along side volume
   B (not sure if this is possible).
3. Copy data to S3 storage from volume A and then transfer it to volume
   B.

What is the preferred method or best practice to get data from volume A to volume B on two instances of the same type?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

All the options are valid. However, I think the simplest would be to attach volume A to instance B, start the instance and copy all the data from volume A to volume B. After that, just unmount volume A and mount it back to instance A.